# error while trying to plot x^2/10 + sin(2x)/2 funtion

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
xnum = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
a = -3
n = 0
d = (((x^2) / (10))+(np.sin(2*x) / (2)))
dfs = ta.derivatives(d, x, a, n)
ta.plotter(xnum, ta.taylor(xnum, a, dfs), d, a)
```

I am getting the error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Not' and 'int'" on my 6th line?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error you're getting.

Comment: `x ^ 2` is not doing what you think it is.  Unless your formula really does involve a bitwise XOR.  Squaring it would look like `x ** 2`

Answer (score 1):

I feel like its the line

```
d = (((x^2) / (10))+(np.sin(2*x) / (2)))
```

that's causing the trouble, power in python is not `^` (which is binary xor), you can use `np.power` or `**` notation.